# Iphone application revenue from AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, ads

Can someone with experience in App Store market. Give me answers of my questions?
I hear stories that people make 5000-10000 $ per day from their app, is it real? 
How may are users on App Store?
How much money you can make from application advertisement, how much apple pay? Per click or per impression?

Please exchange your experience with us, tnx :)

Comment: Unless you plan on finding out the answers to those questions through programming code, this site is not the right one. I would guess programmers.stackexchange.com would be more suited.

Comment: This is completely off topic, as it has nothing to do with code. You may be interested in [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Comment: Just as an aside: I've made some money off of the App Store, but your app needs to be ***remarkable*** to make a decent amount of money off of it.

Comment: Yes, it is real according to credible reports; BUT the odds of making that kind of money from a new paid app in the App store are a very tiny fraction of a percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those numbers are real for a *very small* number of developers.  You're unlikely to get any more detailed stories here, and nothing you do hear will be useful for your own economic projections.

Comment: Do you know something about advertisement program of apple?